# In moderncvtheme , my URLs aren't really pretty :(

Tags: urls

Fresh new with LaTeX, I've a problem with moderncvtheme :

```
\url{http://machin.net/cours-­truc}
```

give me

```
http://machin.net/cours-\discretionary{-}{}{}truc
```

in the final PDF.

Here's my code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.90]{geometry}
\nopagenumbers{}
\title{Conservateur des bibliothèques}
\firstname{Daniel}
\familyname{Bourrion}
\social[twitter][twitter.com/dbourrion]{dbourrion}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Parcours professionnel}
\cventry {2009}{La balade des bibs}{}{Master Pro Histoire et Document, spécialité Métiers des archives et des bibliothèques.
\url {http://fr.slideshare.net/dbourrion/cours-­m2­-histoire­-archives­-bibliothques­-30112009}}{}{}
Same result with : 
\href{http://fr.slideshare.net/dbourrion/cours-­m2­-histoire­-archives­-bibliothques­-30112009}{http://fr.slideshare.net/dbourrion/cours-­m2­-histoire­-archives­-bibliothques­-30112009}
\end{document}
```

Any idea ?
Thanks.
Best regards.
D.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi. Yep, please a look :

Answer (score 1):

Moderncv provides the `\link[text]{actual link}` and `\httplink`(same syntax) for displaying links. Those work fine for me, you should try and stick with them. Unfortunately I'm on mobile thus unable to provide an example

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help but 
`\httplink[httplink http://fr.slideshare.net/dbourrion/m2­-bibproangers2015­52928296]{fr.slideshare.net/dbourrion/m2­-bibproangers2015­52928296}`
comes out in my pdf like 
`http://fr.slideshare.net/dbourrion/m2\discretionary {-}{}{}-bibproangers2015\discretionary {-}{}{}52928296`
Too bad :(

Comment: @dbourrion of course you shouldn't put the actual link in the optional argument of `httplink`

Comment: Oh... got it - I was typing `httplink[httplink text]{actual link}`but the right way is `httplink[text]{actual link}`
It works now, thanks